# prolog: subsets of length k

Tags: prolog, subset

in class we went over the subset_of/2 predicate that my teacher gave as follows:

```
subset_of([],[]).
subset_of([X|Xs],Zs):-subset_of(Xs,Ys),maybe_add(X,Ys,Zs).

maybe_add(_,Ys,Ys).
maybe_add(X,Ys,[X|Ys]).

subsets_of(Xs,Xss):-findall(Ys,subset_of(Xs,Ys),Xss).
```

He then asked us to change it to only give the subsets of some length K (but not by using length/2, by directly finding a recursive definition). My first attempt was to split up the subset_of call into one that adds the extra element and one that does not (instead of having the maybe_add call) and to keep track of the length of the list that was passed and check at the end, but this did not work as planned at all.

```
subset_of(K, 0, [],[]).
subset_of(K, Len, [X|Xs],Zs):-
        L1 is Len - 1,
        subset_of(K, L1, Xs, Zs),
        L1 == K.
subset_of(K, Len, [X|Xs],Zs):-
        L1 is Len - 1,
        subset_of(K, L1, Xs,Ys),
        do_add(X, Ys, Zs),
        Len == K.
subsets_of(K,Xs,Xss):-
        length(Xs, Len),
        findall(Ys,subset_of(K, Len, Xs,Ys),Xss).
```

I am NOT asking for the correct code to solve this, but only a push in the right direction so I can keep trying to figure it out. This is my first time with a declarative languange and I am pretty confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want a direct answer, than I'd say that it can be done much simpler. I've got 3 rules in my solution. However I don't use this additional `maybe_add` formula or anything that resambles it. If you really need it, it can be used and it takes 5 arguments then  - 3 input arguments and 2 output arguments. This reduces the number of rules for `subset_of` to only 2, just as in the original solution. They are quite similar after all.

Also watch out for repetitions. I think `subset_of(0, _, [])` as suggested in other answer may be a way that leads to repetitions. However there might be a correct solution that incorporates it, I'm not sure that there isn't.

Think of it as a proof of correctness. Say you wanted to prove recursively that one set is a K-element subset of another. How would you go about it. Look at the implications that you used. How can you turn them into Prolog rules?

Comment: so i thought about what you said about proving recursively that one set is a k-element subset of another and this is what I have come up with. if something is a k subset, then if you take the first element out the rest should be a k-1 subset which led to this code `ksubset_of(0, _, []).
ksubset_of(K, [X|Xs], Zs) :- K1 is K - 1,
        ksubset_of(K1, Xs, Ys),
        Zs = [X|Ys].`

but this only generates the first one so I dont know where to go from here

Comment: This is ok, and you already have candidates for two rules. However the proof is incomplete and therefore you miss the third rule. Side note: Don't write unifications like this `Zs = [X | Ys]`. You should exchange all the `Zs` for its actual value. This will not only be clearer but also more efficient.

Comment: Think of them as ordered sets which they are after all. It's because they are ordered that your proof is incomplete. That's I guess, what I wanted to say.

Comment: ah yes! after taking out the first element there are two things you can do: 1. add k-1 subsets to the element to get a k subset, or 2. ignore it and generate k-subsets from the list without it. so my final set of rules is this `ksubset_of(0, [], []).
ksubset_of(K, [X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :- K1 is K - 1, ksubset_of(K1, Xs, Ys).
ksubset_of(K, [X|Xs], Ys) :- ksubset_of(K, Xs, Ys).` which looks to be working exactly as it should. You were right about the first rule causing duplicates as well so i had to change that. Thanks for all your help julkiewicz i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Not using `maybe_add` seems like a good idea. However, you don't need two extra arguments: one will do. Your base clause would be

```
subset_of(0, _, []).
```

i.e., the empty set is a zero-element subset of anything. Of the two recursive clauses, one would look for `K-1`-element subsets, the other for `K`-sized subsets.